# Order list by specific starting time

Tags: python, list, time

I have a list of sessions:

```
    sessions = [{
        "session_start": "02:00",
        "session_end": "04:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "02:00",
        "session_end": "04:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "06:00",
        "session_end": "08:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "06:00",
        "session_end": "08:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "08:30",
        "session_end": "11:00",
    }, {
        "session_start": "08:30",
        "session_end": "11:00",
    }, {
        "session_start": "11:00",
        "session_end": "13:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "11:00",
        "session_end": "13:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "13:30",
        "session_end": "16:00",
    }, {
        "session_start": "13:30",
        "session_end": "16:00",
    }, {
        "session_start": "16:00",
        "session_end": "18:30",
    }, {
        "session_start": "16:00",
        "session_end": "18:30",
    }
    ]
```

I want to sort this list by `session_start`, where the first element will be anything after or on `06:00`.

The list was random, and I sorted it to what we have now, which is in time order, but I want this order from a specific 'seed' time value, i.e. `06:00`

What I've done is:

```
  x = sorted(sessions, key=lambda s: time.strptime(s['session_start'], "%H:%M") > time.strptime("06:00", "%H:%M"))
```

This just gives me the same results as before.

Ideal scenario:

```
sessions = [06:00 .....(middle sessions).......02:00]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by " I want this order from a specific 'seed' time value, i.e. 06:00"? Go round the clock from starting at that time?

Comment: Sidenote: you can sort by `key=lambda s: s['session_start']`, no need for `strptime`. String comparison will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
numbers = []
seed = 6.00
ordered_sessions = []
i = 0
for d in sessions:
    numbers.append(float(d['session_start'].replace(':', '.')))
for it in numbers:
    if it < seed:
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 24
    i += 1
numbers = sorted(numbers)
i = 0
for item in numbers:
    if item >= 24:
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] - 24
    i += 1
for item in numbers:
    ordered_sessions.append(str(item).replace('.', ':'))
```

ordered_sessions should be a list with all "session_start" ordered.

Careful: this outputs a list with strings like "2:0", not "02:00".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking at time elapsed since 6am. Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
    
fsort = lambda v: abs(datetime.strptime(v['session_start'], "%H:%M")-datetime.strptime("06:00", "%H:%M")).total_seconds() + \ 
                  60*60*24 if datetime.strptime(v['session_start'], "%H:%M") < datetime.strptime("06:00", "%H:%M") else 0
x = sorted(sessions, key=fsort)
```

Your original code is checking for an inequality not a time lapsed.